# Trouble selecting the correct information from a left join

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I am changing a string field into a reference. I have already stashed my old data and changed the column type, so now I'm just trying to update the newly converted column with the correct information from the old column.

I have the following logic:

```
UPDATE myapp_assignment SET home_hr_support = 
  (SELECT id FROM 
      (SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT home_hr_support_old, home_hr_support FROM myapp_assignment) a
    LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT id, CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS fullname FROM users) b
    ON a.home_hr_support_old = b.fullname
    WHERE fullname = home_hr_support_old LIMIT 1
  ) c 
); 

SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT home_hr_support_old, home_hr_support FROM myapp_assignment) a
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT id, CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS fullname FROM users) b
  ON a.home_hr_support_old = b.fullname;
```

This returns rows of results like the following:

```
home_hr_support_old | home_hr_support | id | fullname
----------------------------------------------------------
Clark Kent          | 1               | 1  | Clark Kent
Clark Kent          | 1               | 1  | Clark Kent
Homer Simpson       | 1               | 3  | Homer Simpson
Homer Simpson       | 1               | 3  | Homer Simpson
Jon Snow            | 1               | 5  | Jon Snow
Jon Snow            | 1               | 5  | Jon Snow
```

As you can see, the query I'm running is not updating the `home_hr_support` column with the correct user number.

I would hope that Homer Simpson would have a `home_hr_support` value of 3, while Jon Snow would get a 5.

I feel like I'm close to having a solution to this, but I'm clearly doing something wrong. Anyone care to chime in and spotlight my mistake?

====

EDIT: DDLs and fiddle of same:

```
CREATE TABLE `myapp_assignment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `home_hr_support` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `home_hr_support_old` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_13D6985C1F4E43E0` (`home_hr_support`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=501 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(180) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO myapp_assignment (id, home_hr_support, home_hr_support_old) VALUES(1, NULL, "Clark Kent");
INSERT INTO myapp_assignment (id, home_hr_support, home_hr_support_old) VALUES(2, NULL, "Clark Kent");
INSERT INTO myapp_assignment (id, home_hr_support, home_hr_support_old) VALUES(3, NULL, "Homer Simpson");
INSERT INTO myapp_assignment (id, home_hr_support, home_hr_support_old) VALUES(4, NULL, "Homer Simpson");
INSERT INTO myapp_assignment (id, home_hr_support, home_hr_support_old) VALUES(5, NULL, "Jon Snow");
INSERT INTO myapp_assignment (id, home_hr_support, home_hr_support_old) VALUES(6, NULL, "Jon Snow");

INSERT INTO users (id, username, first_name, last_name) VALUES(1, "ckent", "Clark", "Kent");
INSERT INTO users (id, username, first_name, last_name) VALUES(3, "hsimpson", "Homer", "Simpson");
INSERT INTO users (id, username, first_name, last_name) VALUES(5, "jsnow", "Jon", "Snow");
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2faiyqhVFWqnfNPi91eF96/0

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks, Strawberry. I have added a fiddle at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM myapp_assignment x 
  JOIN users y 
    ON CONCAT_WS(' ',y.first_name,y.last_name) = x.home_hr_support_old;
+----+-----------------+---------------------+----+----------+------------+-----------+
| id | home_hr_support | home_hr_support_old | id | username | first_name | last_name |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+----+----------+------------+-----------+
|  1 |            NULL | Clark Kent          |  1 | ckent    | Clark      | Kent      |
|  2 |            NULL | Clark Kent          |  1 | ckent    | Clark      | Kent      |
|  3 |            NULL | Homer Simpson       |  3 | hsimpson | Homer      | Simpson   |
|  4 |            NULL | Homer Simpson       |  3 | hsimpson | Homer      | Simpson   |
|  5 |            NULL | Jon Snow            |  5 | jsnow    | Jon        | Snow      |
|  6 |            NULL | Jon Snow            |  5 | jsnow    | Jon        | Snow      |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+----+----------+------------+-----------+

UPDATE myapp_assignment x 
  JOIN users y 
    ON CONCAT_WS(' ',y.first_name,y.last_name) = x.home_hr_support_old 
   SET x.home_hr_support = y.id;

SELECT * FROM myapp_assignment;
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
| id | home_hr_support | home_hr_support_old |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
|  1 |               1 | Clark Kent          |
|  2 |               1 | Clark Kent          |
|  3 |               3 | Homer Simpson       |
|  4 |               3 | Homer Simpson       |
|  5 |               5 | Jon Snow            |
|  6 |               5 | Jon Snow            |
+----+-----------------+---------------------+
```